# Um, but I have a portal?

Tags: blockheads

I have been playing **Blockheads** for a bit and I want to create a trade portal. Problem is, the requirements are asking me for these objects:

[image]

The portal I am using IS another portal, a completely different portal than the portal I started out with. (So basically, I bought another portal, and this was the second one).

Is there something wrong with the game, or do I need more portals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to have the portal in your inventory for it to craft a trade portal, my good Monsieur. So the gist of it is that you need to have a portal ON you, not using the portal, so just take 1 of the portals, go to the other, then craft the trade portal just like that.

Comment: Thanks! That helped! I have no clue who down voted this question